# Anaconda python: Pinning channel and not package version

Tags: python, package, anaconda, conda

Every time I use `conda install -c some_channel` to install a Python package, conda tries to update other packages from `some_channel`. From example, here I'm trying to install `hdbscan` from `conda-forge`, and conda wants to update `ca-certificates` as well.

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    hdbscan:         0.8.18-py36h7eb728f_0 conda-forge

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0          anaconda    --> 2018.8.24-ha4d7672_0 conda-forge
    certifi:         2018.8.24-py36_1      anaconda    --> 2018.8.24-py36_1001  conda-forge
    openssl:         1.0.2p-h1de35cc_0     anaconda    --> 1.0.2p-h470a237_1    conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? n
```

**Note** that conda tries to do this even if the package versions from the two channels are identical. So this is not just about upgrading to newer version.

Can I pin the channel for packages without pinning the version numbers? I wouldn't mind updating `ca-certificates` if the update comes from `anaconda` channel.

Comment: I guess there is no 100% safe way to do what yout want (see https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-install.html). What might work is `--no-update-dependencies` - but no guarantee ;)

Comment: Please do not post code/terminal output in images. Please see here for why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192

Comment: The way that I get around this problem is to **append** the channel of interest to my configuration: `conda config --append channels some-channel`. That way, the `defaults` channel has a higher priority for packages that are available from the `defaults` channel. If I decide I want a specific package from a channel that is a lower priority, I can do `conda install some-channel::package-name`

Comment: That right, @user69453, `--no-update-dependencies` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Regarding channel priorities, I do have a `.condarc` in my home directory (assuming that that would affect all conda environments). The channel priority in this file is `defaults`, `anaconda`, and then `conda-forge`. Moreover, it has `channel_priority: True` and `update_dependencies: False`. Same problem still.

Comment: i use this to pin to channels: `conda config --env --add pinned_packages conda-forge::gdal`